# Get the value of an variable inside a thread while running a loop(python)

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

i'm trying to get files name's in a ftp directory.acctualy my problem is that i get eatch time an empty string when i use a loop.in case that i run my program without a lopp i get the right files name's.
This is my program

```
class Watch:

    def __init__(self):
     self.m=""
    def goh(self):
     while True:
        j = 0
        ftp = FTP('')
        ftp.connect('127.0.0.1', 1026)
        ftp.login(user='user', passwd='12345')
        ftp.cwd("/FTM/Simulateur/1.MPTC_ACK")
        files = ftp.nlst()
        while j < len(files):
            timestamp = ftp.voidcmd("MDTM " + files[j])[4:].strip()
            time = parser.parse(timestamp)
            self.time_dic = str(time)
            self.tab_file = files[j]
            os.chdir("/Users/ouhejjouyou/Desktop/eleclink/Fichier_in/1.MPTC_ACK")
            fhandle = open(files[j], 'wb')
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + str(self.tab_file), fhandle.write)
            fhandle.close()
            ftp.delete(self.tab_file)
            self.m = self.time_dic + " Reception du fichier " + self.tab_file + " réussi\n"
            j = j + 1

a=Watch()
t = Thread(target=a.goh)
t.start()
print(a.m)
t.join()
```

Comment: Perhaps you should `print(a.m)` after `t.join()`.

Comment: Your program executes a loop that potentially changes the value of the member variable `m` many times, but it only prints the value of `m` one time. Which value of `m` did you intend it to print?  Why did you put the `print(a.m)` call in a different thread from the assignment to `m`? Why do you think your program needs more than one thread?

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried to out the print (a.m) after the t.join but it doesn't work

Comment: Actually I need to excute my program using a thred because I need the display the value of the variable m in my gui. I have succeeded to display the right value only without using a loop.in case of using a loop I get an empty str as declared in Def _in it. Using qthread I have emit a signal to get the value of m, but how I could do it just using a normal thred? Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Re, "...display the value...in my gui." I've never written a GUI program in Python, but I don't think that `print(a.m)` is going to display anything in a GUI widget. If you haven't re-defined it, then `print()` will only send text to the program's standard output stream (e.g., to the console if you started the program from a command line, or maybe to nowhere if you started it some other way.)